# Xposed: How to connect Xposed module to database without SD read permission?

Tags: android

I'm developing an Xposed framework based module on Android.

The main application maintains a Sqlite database.

The Xposed module requires to connect to the database, however the module runs within the package context it is hooked too (runs not as my application, but as another application).

The problem is some applications don't request the SD read permission thus preventing the injected module code from reading the database file on SD card.

How can I  access the database for the Xposed hook, WITHOUT access to a Context object (can't call a remote service) ?

Note that root privileges is available.